# Microsoft UVC driver streaming RAW data with web camera instead of Compressed data

Tags: camera, driver, directshow

As per mentioned link [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110807021632/http://www.quickcamteam.net/documentation/faq/what-video-streaming-formats-are-supported) :
My Logitech camera will stream I420 and RGB24 with Logitech driver .

But ,With the Microsoft UVC driver, camera should stream YUY2 and MJPG formats.
But still I am getting RGB24 type of data .
PFB the snap shot of the camera driver in my laptop [image]

```
 I am new to the driver level side and don't know more about drivers .
```

**My understanding is** I am having Microsoft UVC driver got installed for camera ,
but still camera is streaming with RGB24 type of RAW data .

I am using Directshow to capture the camera data . 
Is there any software/tool by which I can check the type of data from USB camera devices.

CAN YOU PLEASE COMMENT ON MY UNDERSTANDING !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check camera capabilities using `DirectShowCaptureCapabilities` tool:

- `Win32` build - [`DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-Win32.exe`](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Toolbox/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-Win32.exe)
- `x64` build - [`DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-x64.exe`](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Toolbox/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-x64.exe)

The app gives a textual representation of capabilities available through DirectShow API, where you can get the information in question.

In particular, some output is presented [here](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data/), posted by tool users. Let's look at [USB2.0 UVC HQ WebCam](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data/USB2.0%20UVC%20HQ%20WebCam.md) output:

> - `.subtype`: `FourCC MJPG`
> - `.subtype`: `FourCC YUY2`

The lines above are taken from media types Motion JPEG and raw YUY2 respectively.

Comment: my camera c920 logitech is showing `.subtype`: `FourCC H264` ..But when I checked the data i received from opencv based cap.read() function ,it is RGB24 raw data .Not compressed ..Can you comment on this .

Comment: OpenCV typically needs raw data for processing. So you basically see the expected behavior: the camera is either set to deliver data in well known uncompressed format, or it sends H.264 and video is decoded before reaching you.

Comment: As I checked openCV retrieve() function which is used for doing decoding of the grabframe by using grab() function ,I observed that in retrieve function there is only copy of data from source to destination instead of actual decoding .

Comment: Decoding might take place at earlier stage, you need to inspect filter graph to see if decoder is there before grabbing filter.